# C++ program to convert decimal to binary is getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++

This is a c++ program to convert decimal number to binary number. Well there are many possible ways to implement this but as I learned about the static variable I thought to make a use of it. So the program is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int **binary(int num, int &k) {
    static int *p;
    int i = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        *p = num % 2;
        p++;
        num = num / 2;
        k++;
    }
    return &p;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "\n Enter the number to be converted into binary : ";
    cin >> n;
    int **ptr;
    ptr = binary(n, k);
    cout << "\n The number of bytes in the binary number is : " << k << endl;
    cout << "\n The binary code is : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << **(ptr+i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 Enter the number to be converted into binary : 33
Segmentation fault
```

After debugging this code I'm getting seg fault at line 9:9 
i.e

```
*p = num % 2;
```

I don't know why this is leading me to access an unoccupied memory space in the stack.

Comment: Probably `p` is a invalid pointer at some time, thus derefencing may cause a crash.

Comment: `at some time` meaning?

Comment: See @chqrlie's answer.

Comment: Always. You have never initialized it. See the answer.

Comment: There is no *decimal* to binary conversion going on here.  an `int` already is binary.  You are simply representing (or attempting to) represent it with some other encoding.

Comment: @Clifford yes, actually there is not.. but for our school it's sufficient.

Comment: But why all of this pointer gymnastics just to turn a decimal into binary?  Especially this: `int **ptr`.  What's that all about?  It's like you wrote this to seg fault on purpose.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's just fun.. playing with pointers :)

Comment: It's 2016. It's time to embrace the 1990's and use `std::vector`. And to open a book and read the chapter on pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo by the way... happy new year to you and your family :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason there is a crash is that `p` is initialized to `nullptr`. Dereferencing an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, hence you get the crash.

**Disclaimer:** The following code is intended to fix *your* code. It is not intended to illustrate a proper way of doing this, or show a good way to code in general.

If you wish to play with function-static variables, and your function must return a pointer to pointer, initialize `p` by pointing it to another `static` variable which provides you with a buffer:

```
static int pVal[100];
static int * p;
p = pVal; // This should be done in an assignment, not in initializer
```

**Note:** Returning pointers to `static` storage makes your code non-reentrant, which is generally a very bad practice. This code is fine as a learning exercise, but it's not something one should use in production code.

Comment: Right, but it willl crash again because he is increasing the pointer with `p++;`. Maybe he needs an array? To be honest I don't understand what conversion is it... From an integer to a series of integers pointed by `p`??? Moreover he returns a pointer to a locally instantiated variable that will not exist after leaving the function.

Comment: @Frankie_C Yes, that's why I edited the code to make `pVal` an array as soon as I spotted `p++` in OP's example. Returning a pointer to pointer is completely unnecessary, but as a learning exercise it would be OK.

Comment: Maybe to return a local array is not so good anyway... You should specify that is allocated in caller space.

Comment: @Frankie_C The variable is local, but the allocation is static, so the behavior is well-defined (though definitely not re-entrant, which is the point of the note at the end of the answer).

Comment: Yes, of course, I meant an automatic (local) array. But I badly formed the comment, then was too late to correct it. Anyway, as also @chqrlie says,  it's always better to define arrays in caller space to avoid old known problems of some historic (or prehistoric) C functions that return static buffers...

Comment: `p` is not *uninitialized*, it is `static`, therefore it is initialized to `0`. This answer is too shallow: `p` needs to be `static` because the API is uselessly awkward and confused, using a `static` array is bad practice anyway and unnecessary.  There are more problems with the OP's code.

Comment: @chqrlie Making `p` `static` is required in order to return a pointer to pointer. Returning a pointer to pointer, on the other hand, is not required, so `p` could be made non-static only if the signature changed to `int*` from `int**`.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree. The user seems also to want to use stack to **reverse** the binary conversion, based on a strange idea of stack behavior...

Comment: Worse than that: `cout << **(ptr+i);` will not read the binary bits, it will invoke undefined behavior for any non trivial value of `n`.  It should be `cout << (*ptr)[i];`  or better `cout << (*ptr)[k - i];`

Answer (score 1):

`static int * p;` is never set.  It is initialized to `NULL`, dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. Using a static buffer is not recommended, it is better to pass an array to the function and return the number of bits.  Furthermore, you should output these bits in the reverse order.

Since you are interested in `static` local variables, here is a corrected version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *binary(int num, int &k) {
    static int bits[sizeof(int) * 8];
    int *p = bits;
    k = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        *p = num % 2;
        p++;
        num = num / 2;
        k++;
    }
    return p;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "\n Enter the number to be converted into binary : ";
    cin >> n;
    int *ptr = binary(n, k);
    cout << "\n The number of bits in the binary number is : " << k << endl;
    cout << "\n The binary code is : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << ptr[k - i];
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a version that does not use a static buffer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int binary(unsigned int num, int *dest) {
    for (int i = 0;;) {
        dest[i++] = num & 1;
        if ((num >>= 1) == 0)
            return i;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned n;
    int bits[sizeof(n) * 8];

    cout << "\nEnter the number to be converted into binary: ";
    cin >> n;

    int k = binary(n, bits);
    cout << "\nThe number of bits in the binary number is: " << k << endl;
    cout << "\nThe binary code is: ";
    for (int i = k; i-- > 0;)
        cout << bits[i];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you just changed the whole idea in the code... I made this just to have example of static variable. I understand that my code has problems and I guess those problems are nothing in-front of your code... Have you try running your code? It too had seg fault and the worst part is that even on debugging this code I can't find the seg fault... There is no doubt you're great but not this time... I have known you long before... Happy new year

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote this code. Even you applied a new logic for conversion. There are really many different ways to do that and the question wasn't about that.

Comment: @rajaTHEKING: Sorry about this, I jump directly to the code and did not read your precise elements of context.  There were indeed a few typos in my code that prevented compilation and would cause an infinite loop. My bad.

Comment: you never need to say sorry to me... despite you are helping. I still remember the first time you take me louvre when i was kid of 6.

Comment: @rajaTHEKING: Really?  When was that?

Comment: wait... coming to your doorstep in few minutes ... also would love to have a cup of coffee.

Comment: @rajaTHEKING: still waiting... and 10pm is a bit late for coffee ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The code has numerous problems:

- `binary()` does not initialise the pointer `p` to anything.
- `binary()` dereferences the initialised `p` and modifies the value.
- The conversion writes from LSB to MSB and the outputs writes in that order too.

You need to allocate a buffer to receive the conversion.  This is safest done by the caller.  Since ultimately you output the characters `1` or `0`, your conversion may as well write those character values directly to a string.